# How to extract the logic of validating fields inside angular reactive form template?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In my template I am displaying error messages based on if the field is valid or not. Each time I need an *ngIf that checks if the control is touched and valid .In order to make the template more readable I extracted that logic into a function inside the component:

```
isFieldValid(field: string) {
    console.log("in is field valid");

    return !!(
      !this.form.get(field)?.valid &&
      this.form.get(field)?.touched
    );
  }
```

But after adding the console.log I saw that this function is called way too many times. I assume this may cause a performance issues in the long term. What can I do in order to make that logic reusable but also not cause so many unnecessary calls?

Comment: this function must return boolean for me

Comment: No, In angular it's not recommended to call functions inside of template. Just read this article  https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496#:~:text=To%20avoid%20issues%2C%20it%20is,pipe's%20input%20does%20not%20change

Comment: ok, so what is the solution to use in my case ?